# How to access GridView,ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode with C# in windows 10 winrt?

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-runtime, windows-10

I have a xaml code something of this sort

```
 <GridView x:Name="gv" Margin="8,0,8,8" 
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                        <Some data with Binding Here>
                   </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
   </GridView>
```

Now I want to enable the vertical scroll based on a condition from my C# end, But I cant access it with `gv.ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode` . What am I doing wrong. And if this is not possible what are the other alternatives?

Comment: FYI: those are called attached properties. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758282.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it from code behing using static method `ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollMode`

Example:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

//...

ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollMode(gv, ScrollMode.Disabled);
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for!